# skipping a variable using while read in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

i'm reading a few variables from a file using

```
while read a b c; do
  (something)
done < filename
```

is there an elegant way to skip a variable (read in an empty value), i.e. if I want a=1 b= c=3, what should I write in the file?

Right now i'm putting

```
1 "" 3
```

and then use

b=$(echo $b | tr -d \" )

but this is pretty cumbersome, IMHO

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a blank field:

> 1  3

You can do:

```
if [[ -z c ]]
then
    c=b
    b=
fi
```

If your data is comma delimited, you can also do:

```
while IFS=, read a b c
```

(but you'll have problems if your fields contain commas, as you may in your current version if they contain quotes):

> 1,,3

Also, in your version instead of using `tr`, you can do:

```
b=${b//\"\"}
```

but you can eliminate that step altogether using the following with your current data format:

```
while IFS='"' read a b c
```

however, comma-delimited fields is a more common format.

Comment: this would work only if there is only one optional variable, but I have more than one, unfortunately.

But +1 for getting rid of tr  in any case ;)

Comment: @Aleksandar: The comma-delimited version would work for any number of fields. `1,,3,4,5,,7`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood what you want but you can skip certain values of the iteration (be it while, for or whatever) with **continue** and even stop the iteration with **break**

```
while read a b c ;do 
   if [[ $b == 0 || $c == 0 || $a == 0 ]];then
      continue
   fi      
   (makelovenotwar)
done < /foo/bar
```

Comment: No, by "skipping" I meant putting an empty value into a variable